# Renew arraystretch only inside matrix environment

Tags: tables, spacing, matrices, arrays

I am using `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}` in my arrays to produce nice tables. But this is affecting also matrix environments. Supposedly one can redefine the `\arraystretch` locally inside each environment, but this does not work when I try to make my matrices look nice again. Please help.

Here's a MWE (which also illustrates the issue):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\begin{document}

 \[\begin{array}{|c|c|}
  \hline \omega^s_{~s}= 0 & \omega^s_{~\theta}= -\dfrac{f'}{f}\,\theta^\theta \\[.5em] \hline  \omega^\theta_{~s}=\dfrac{f'}{f}\,\theta^\theta & \omega^\theta_{~\theta}=0 \\[.5em] \hline
\end{array}\]

 \[  \begin{vmatrix} \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{.5}
g(u_1,v_1) & g(u_1,v_2) \\ g(u_2,v_1) & g(u_2,v_2)    
  \end{vmatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\bgroup` and `\egroup` for that.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}
\begin{document}
% your araystretch
 \[\begin{array}{|c|c|}
  \hline \omega^s_{~s}= 0 & \omega^s_{~\theta}= -\dfrac{f'}{f}\,\theta^\theta \\[.5em] \hline  \omega^\theta_{~s}=\dfrac{f'}{f}\,\theta^\theta & \omega^\theta_{~\theta}=0 \\[.5em] \hline
\end{array}\]
% araystretch locally redefined
 \[  \bgroup\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{.5}\begin{vmatrix} 
g(u_1,v_1) & g(u_1,v_2) \\ g(u_2,v_1) & g(u_2,v_2)    
  \end{vmatrix}\egroup\]
% your araystretch again
 \[\begin{array}{|c|c|}
  \hline \omega^s_{~s}= 0 & \omega^s_{~\theta}= -\dfrac{f'}{f}\,\theta^\theta \\[.5em] \hline  \omega^\theta_{~s}=\dfrac{f'}{f}\,\theta^\theta & \omega^\theta_{~\theta}=0 \\[.5em] \hline
\end{array}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fast answer, works nice, and I learned something new (I had never heard of `\bgroup` and `\egroup`, thanks!

Comment: `\bgroup` and `\egroup` aren't really needed. Putting `\renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{.5}` before `\begin{vmatrix}` works as expected.

Comment: This is curious. I figured the actual "array" wouldn't begin until the `\begin{vmatrix}`.

Comment: @corporal Not if the second array is in the same equation.

Comment: @IvoTerek `\bgroup...\egroup` is the same as `{...}` in most places, so there's nothing really new.Not in this case, but using `{...}` for making some setting local in math mode could introduce bad spacing; better using `\begingroup...\endgroup`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to do it without plaguing the typescript with `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{...}`. Every `Xmatrix` environment in `amsmath` is defined in terms of `\env@matrix`; since environments form groups, the setting of `\arraystretch` will be local.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath, etoolbox}

\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2.5}

\makeatletter
\preto\env@matrix{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\omega^s_{~s}= 0 & \omega^s_{~\theta}= -\dfrac{f'}{f}\,\theta^\theta \\[.5em]
\hline
\omega^\theta_{~s}=\dfrac{f'}{f}\,\theta^\theta & \omega^\theta_{~\theta}=0 \\[.5em]
\hline
\end{array}
\\
\begin{vmatrix}
g(u_1,v_1) & g(u_1,v_2) \\ 
g(u_2,v_1) & g(u_2,v_2)
\end{vmatrix}
\end{gather*}

\end{document}
```

[image]